# how to get index of the current collided object in corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a table called `ob1` which contains 10 images(these are created randomly & moved horizontally), i have a bar at the middle of screen, i have enabled physics for both & implemented collision event listener to remove `ob1` image when they collide with bar but the problem is that when 3-4 images are approaching toward bar & when the first `ob1` collides with bar random `ob1` object are getting removed but not the current `ob1` object, how can i get the id of current collided `ob1` object ?

code is

```
local ob1={}
for i=1,obslimit do
    ob1[i]=display.newImage( "images/ob1.png", 250,250)
    ob1[i].isVisible=false
    ob1[i].isAlive=false
    physics.addBody( ob1[i], "dynamic", {friction=1,bounce=0.0})
    ob1[i].gravityScale=0
    ob1[i].isBodyActive=false
end

--function to deal ob1 collision
local function ob1cols( self,event )
    if(event.phase=="began") then
        --print(self.myName..event.other.myName)
        local ob1_elem = require("mydata")
        --ob1_elem.new.isBodyActive=false
        ob1_elem.new.isVisible=false
        ob1_elem.new.isAlive=false
    end
end

--function to deal ob1 group pooling
local function getob1()
    --calling ob1 from pool
    for i=1, #ob1 do
        if not ob1[i].isAlive then
            --print( "got one" ) 
            return ob1[i]
        end
    end
    return nil
end

--function to deal obstacle spawning
local function obdecide(event)
    if (mytime==100) then
        --local ob1_elem = getob1()
        local ob1_elem = require("mydata")
        ob1_elem.new=getob1()
        if (ob1_elem.new~=nil) then
            ob1_elem.new.isVisible=true
            ob1_elem.new.isAlive=true
            ob1_elem.new.isBodyActive=true
            ob1_elem.new.x=math.random( 200,350 )
            --trying to add event listner for every object
            ob1_elem.new.myName="cactus"
            ob1_elem.new:setLinearVelocity( -20, 0 )
            ob1_elem.new.collision=ob1cols
            ob1_elem.new:addEventListener( "collision", ob1_elem.new)
        end
    elseif (mytime>100) then
        mytime=0
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- add an ID field for each object like this:
local ob1={}
for i=1,obslimit do
    ob1[i].id = i -- ** this is what I mean ** --
    ob1[i]=display.newImage( "images/ob1.png", 250,250)
    ob1[i].isVisible=false
    ob1[i].isAlive=false
    physics.addBody( ob1[i], "dynamic", {friction=1,bounce=0.0})
    ob1[i].gravityScale=0
    ob1[i].isBodyActive=false
end
```

in the collision listener try this implementation:

```
function onCollision (event)
    if (event.object1.id == 1 or event.object2.id == 1) then
        -- object collided is obj1[1]
    elseif (event.object1.id == 2 or event.object2.id == 2) then
        -- object collided is obj1[2]
        -- and so on. I hope you got this so far.
    and
end
```

Comment: I tried your solution but no luck :( (it's throwing nil reference error) , i just want to remove that partilcuar object which collided with bar at the moment, it would be great if there is a way to do that.

Comment: @caesargetit yeah. I meant the code you tried this solution. sorry for not clarifying

Comment: your `id` idea gave me another idea, i.e to declare `object.myName` for every object in table & accessing them through that name & now my problem is solved completely thanx

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> ob1[i].name="object";
>
> ```
> local function onLocalCollision( event,self )
>
> if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
>
> elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
>   if (event.other.name = "object") then
>     event.other:removeSelf()
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> end

bar.collision = onLocalCollision
  bar:addEventListener( "collision", bar)

Comment: i used `object.myName` for every `table object` & the problem is solved now